# Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. How can i solve this for react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to change the textures of the different components of the 3d models,but when i click of the leva controlbox options to select the state to show the materialMenu for that specific component it is showing this error.

here is the code of Scene.jsx:

```
 
import React, { useMemo, useRef } from 'react'
import { Decal, useGLTF, useTexture } from '@react-three/drei'
import * as THREE from 'three';
 
import {floorObj,cabinObj,chairObj,tableObj} from '../../../public/models/dinning_room/secondary_materials'

export default function Model({Color,componentSelect,textureSelect,...props}) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('public/models/dinning_room/scene.gltf');
const floorRef=useRef();
 
console.log("texture",textureSelect);

   const texture = useMemo(() => {
    const textureSource = floorObj[textureSelect >= 0 && componentSelect == 0 ? textureSelect : 0];
    return useTexture(textureSource);
  }, [componentSelect, textureSelect]);

//   const textureSource = floorObj[textureSelect >= 0 && componentSelect == 0 ? textureSelect : 0];
// const texture=useTexture(textureSource);
   texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
   texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
   texture.repeat.set(5, 5); // Adjust the values to control the tiling density
 console.log("t: ",texture)
 

const cabTex = useMemo(() => {
  const textureSource = cabinObj[textureSelect >= 0 && componentSelect == 3 ? textureSelect : 0];
  return useTexture(textureSource);
}, [componentSelect, textureSelect]);

// const textureSource1 = cabinObj[textureSelect >= 0 && componentSelect == 3 ? textureSelect : 0];
// const cabTex=useTexture(textureSource1)
cabTex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
cabTex.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
cabTex.repeat.set(1, 1);

 
const chairTex = useMemo(() => {
  const textureSource = chairObj[textureSelect >= 0 && componentSelect == 1 ? textureSelect : 0];
  return useTexture(textureSource);
}, [componentSelect, textureSelect]);

// const textureSource2 = chairObj[textureSelect >= 0 && componentSelect == 1 ? textureSelect : 0];
// const chairTex=useTexture(textureSource2)
chairTex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
chairTex.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
chairTex.repeat.set(20, 2);

 
const tableTex = useMemo(() => {
  const textureSource = tableObj[textureSelect >= 0 && componentSelect == 2 ? textureSelect : 0];
  return useTexture(textureSource);
}, [componentSelect, textureSelect]);

// const textureSource3 = tableObj[textureSelect >= 0 && componentSelect == 2 ? textureSelect : 0];
// const tableTex=useTexture(textureSource3)
tableTex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
tableTex.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
tableTex.repeat.set(2, 1);

  return (
    <group {...props}  dispose={null}>
      <group scale={0.01}>
        <group position={[388.469, 117.552, -211.434]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0.148, 0]} scale={[2.712, 31.279, 31.279]} castShadow >
          <mesh geometry={nodes.painting_Material010_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.010']} castShadow 
          >

            </mesh>
          <mesh geometry={nodes.painting_Material011_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.011']} castShadow receiveShadow>

</mesh>

        </group>
        <group position={[366.217, 115.97, -143.771]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={3.789} castShadow receiveShadow>
          <mesh geometry={nodes.candle_Material013_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.013']} />
          <mesh geometry={nodes.candle_Material008_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.008']} />
          <mesh geometry={nodes.candle_Material007_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.007']} />
        </group>
        <group position={[85.821, 88.279, 64.486]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={100} castShadow receiveShadow>
          <mesh geometry={nodes.flower_leaf2_0.geometry} material={materials.leaf2} />
          <mesh geometry={nodes.flower_leaf1_0.geometry} material={materials.leaf1} />
        </group>
        <group position={[188.831, 243.457, -26.58]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={[2.688, 2.688, 23.024]}>
          <mesh geometry={nodes.lighting_Material001_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.001']} castShadow receiveShadow >
          <meshStandardMaterial  color={'black'}/>
            </mesh>
          <mesh geometry={nodes.lighting_Material003_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.003']} castShadow receiveShadow >
          <meshStandardMaterial  color={'black'}/>

            </mesh>
          <mesh geometry={nodes.lighting_Material014_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.014']} castShadow receiveShadow>
          <meshStandardMaterial  color={'black'}/>

            </mesh>
        </group>
        <group position={[81.651, 59.793, -127.726]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, -Math.PI / 2]} scale={[25.257, 25.257, 2.667]}>
          <mesh geometry={nodes.seat_Leather_0.geometry} material={materials.Leather} >
            <meshStandardMaterial  map={chairTex}/>
            </mesh>

          <mesh geometry={nodes.seat_Material5_0.geometry} material={materials.Material5} >

            </mesh>
        </group>
        <mesh geometry={nodes.house_Material009_0.geometry}
         material={materials['Material.009']} position={[0, 151.309, -0.282]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={[396.176, 396.176, 150]} >
<meshStandardMaterial color={Color}  />
          </mesh>
        <mesh geometry={nodes.cabinet_Material015_0.geometry}
         material={materials['Material.015']} position={[367.527, 300.186, 45.941]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={[34.407, 249.171, 3.605]} >
<meshStandardMaterial map={cabTex}/>
          </mesh>
      
        <mesh geometry={nodes.window_Material016_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.016']} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={100} >

          </mesh>
        <mesh geometry={nodes.table_Material5001_0.geometry}
         material={materials['Material5.001']} position={[83.1, 65.739, 24.667]} 
         rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={[80.747, 80.747, 10.763]} >
<meshStandardMaterial map={tableTex}/>

         </mesh>
       
        <mesh ref={floorRef} geometry={nodes.floor_floor_0.geometry} 
         material={materials.floor} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={100}  dispose={null}>
 
{ textureSelect>=0?(<meshStandardMaterial scale={10}  map={texture} />):null }

          </mesh>




        <mesh geometry={nodes.jar4_Material017_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.017']} position={[377.036, 94.34, 219.292]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={7.771} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.jar3_Material002_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.002']} position={[383.419, 94.983, 239.01]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={8.337} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.vase_grey001_0.geometry} material={materials['grey.001']} position={[85.258, 86.332, 64.115]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={8.337} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.faucet_Material006_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.006']} position={[392.071, 95.046, 141.652]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={[0.204, 0.204, 1.555]} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.bowl_grey_0.geometry} material={materials.grey} position={[372.827, 99.081, 270.913]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={[16.524, 16.524, 12.674]} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.IKEA_seat_wood__0.geometry} material={materials.wood} position={[363.595, 31.995, -331.439]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, -Math.PI / 2]} scale={[17.536, 15.514, 15.514]} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.carpet_Carpet__0.geometry} material={materials.Carpet} position={[81.578, 2.411, 26.536]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={[190.768, 245.015, 0.524]} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.chopping_board1_Material1_0.geometry} material={materials.Material1} position={[388.318, 97.913, 187.245]} rotation={[-1.593, -1.28, -0.023]} scale={[1.332, 1.546, 1.332]} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.chopping_board2_Material2_0.geometry} material={materials.Material2} position={[391.595, 98.773, 194.446]} rotation={[-1.6, -1.347, -0.03]} scale={[1.399, 1.586, 1.399]} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.jar1_Material3_0.geometry} material={materials.Material3} position={[375.22, 92.792, -108.769]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, -1.875]} scale={0.898} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.jar2_Material4_0.geometry} material={materials.Material4} position={[372.586, 97.235, -121.78]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, -1.247]} scale={0.824} />
      </group>
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload('public/models/dinning_room/scene.gltf')
```

ANd here is the codeof the LivingRoom.jsx :

```
import { Environment, Html, OrbitControls, PerspectiveCamera } from '@react-three/drei'
import React, { useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import Model from './Scene'
import { useControls } from 'leva'
import annotations from './annotations.json'
import { useFrame, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import TWEEN  from '@tweenjs/tween.js'
import MaterialMenu from './MaterialMenu'


function Annotations({ controls,selected,setSelected }) {
    const { camera } = useThree()
  console.log("annotationss",selected);
    return (
      <>
        {annotations.map((a, i) => {
          return (
            <Html key={i} position={[a.lookAt.x, a.lookAt.y, a.lookAt.z]}>
              <svg height="34" width="34" transform="translate(-16 -16)" style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                <circle
                  cx="17"
                  cy="17"
                  r="16"
                  stroke="white"
                  strokeWidth="2"
                  fill="rgba(0,0,0,.66)"
                  onPointerUp={() => {
                    setSelected(i)
                    // change target
                    new TWEEN.Tween(controls.current.target)
                      .to(
                        {
                          x: a.lookAt.x,
                          y: a.lookAt.y,
                          z: a.lookAt.z
                        },
                        1000
                      )
                      .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.Out)
                      .start()
  
                    // change camera position
                    new TWEEN.Tween(camera.position)
                      .to(
                        {
                          x: a.camPos.x,
                          y: a.camPos.y,
                          z: a.camPos.z
                        },
                        1000
                      )
                      .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.Out)
                      .start()
                  }}
                />
                <text x="12" y="22" fill="white" fontSize={17} fontFamily="monospace" style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
                  {i + 1}
                </text>
              </svg>
              {a.description && i === selected && (
                <div id={'desc_' + i} className="annotationDescription" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: a.description }} />
              )}
            </Html>
          )
        })}
      </>
    )
  }
  
  function Tween() {
    useFrame(() => {
      TWEEN.update()
    })
  }


const LivingRoom = () => {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(-1)
const [textureSelect,setTextureSelect]=useState(-1);
const [componentSelect,setComponentSelect]=useState(-1);

const ref=useRef();
    const options=useMemo(()=>{
        return{
          x:{value: -7, min: -Math.PI*4, max: Math.PI * 4, step: 0.01},
          y: { value: 0, min:  -Math.PI*4, max: Math.PI * 4, step: 0.01 },
          z: { value: 0, min:  -Math.PI*4, max: Math.PI * 4, step: 0.01 },
          visible: true,
          color: { value: 'white' },
        }
      },[])

      const options2=useMemo(()=>{
        return{
        
          Floor: false,
          Chair: false,
          Table: false,
          Cabinet:false


          // color: { value: 'white' },
        }
      },[])

          console.log("room",selected);
      const p=useControls('Model dimensions ',options);
      const p2=useControls("Texture Change",options2);
let sendValue=null;

      if(p2.Floor==true){
        p2.Chair=false;
        p2.Table=false;
        p2.Cabinet=false;
        sendValue="Floor";
        setComponentSelect(0)
      }else if(p2.Chair==true){
        p2.Table=false;
        p2.Cabinet=false;
        p2.Floor==false;
        sendValue="Chair";
        setComponentSelect(1)
      }else if(p2.Table==true){
        p2.Cabinet=false;
        p2.Floor==false;
        p2.Chair=false;
        sendValue="Table";
        setComponentSelect(2);
      }else if(p2.Cabinet==true){
        p2.Floor==false;
        p2.Chair=false;
        p2.Table=false;
       sendValue="Cabinet";
       setComponentSelect(3);
      }



      console.log("p2 floor:",p2.Floor)
      console.log("p2 chair:",p2.Chair)
      console.log("p2 table:",p2.Table)
      console.log("p2 Cabinet:",p2.Cabinet)
      console.log(sendValue);
      console.log(componentSelect);
  return (
    <>
    <PerspectiveCamera makeDefault position={[p.x,p.y,p.z]}/>
    <OrbitControls target={[0,0,0]} ref={ref} maxPolarAngle={1.45} enableDamping={false} />
    <ambientLight args={['white',0.5]} />
    <Annotations controls={ref} selected={selected} setSelected={setSelected} />
    <Tween />
    {
     sendValue? <MaterialMenu setTextureSelect={setTextureSelect} textureSelect={textureSelect} 
     sendValue={sendValue}
     />:null

    }
    <Environment preset='apartment' />
    <Model position={[0,0,0]} Color={p.color} componentSelect={componentSelect} textureSelect={textureSelect}/>

        </>
  )
}

export default LivingRoom
```

I'm trying to do that when i select any of the options:- Floor,Chair,Cabinet,Table the corresponding materialMenu should loaded up ,and them i click on any of the buttons in the menu ,the desired texture should be applied to that specific component.